# what is this code? can this code steal cookies?

Tags: javascript, popup, xss

excuse me.
I was browsing in a website. and after that, there is a pop-up like it

```
[some text] <div id="extwaiimpotscp" style="display:none" v="{9225" f="ZXpreU1EUTNNamM4TFRBNU1UQXROW0ZpWWkxaVpZSTNMV0UzWmpKalpEWmpfakEwWW4wlQ==" q="b05a3bb7" c="57.45" i="60.47" u="10.30" s="19188318" w="false" m="BMe=" vn="yote2"></div>
```

is that XSS? and can I use it for steal cookies? and how to use?
and what is the name of this code?

[image: This is screenshot of the popup]

Comment: [This?](https://github.com/rainyrainyday/HomebrewOverlay)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a firefox addons probably causing this html to be appended in your code. You can try disabling some addons. Though, it's clearly not harmful for sure.

https://quick-geek.github.io/answers/887067/index.html for reference.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: This code looks like specific XSS if it is XSS. If is not it can be any third party extension for your browser.

This `div` is odd, It might be payload for another JS code, here's sloppy example just curiosity:

```js
// Pick document
const oddAndObviousUnsafeElement = document.getElementById('extwaiimpotscp')
const payload = Object.values(oddAndObviousUnsafeElement).map(attribute => {
  if (neededAttributes.contains(attribute))
    return attribute
})
```

- If you want to steal any cookie here's your receipt.
  **If the cookie does not flagged `HttpOnly`**

  - Prequalifications: *HTML + JS (+ CSS can be attack vector for XSS)* + backend language learn those.
  - [Read OWASP XSS Documentation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)), [Learn when playing](https://xss-game.appspot.com/)

> **Don't** steal cookies. Write it down how you crack the gap and report it. That can be better for you.